# Use SSH key of host during Singularity/Apptainer build

Tags: git, ssh-keys, singularity-container, apptainer

**When building a Singularity/Apptainer image from a definition file, is there a portable way to make a SSH key of the host system available during the build?**

To give some context:

I have a definition file where in the `%post` section I'm cloning a private git repository using SSH, i.e.:

```
git clone git@github.com:luator/private_repo.git
```

This fails because the SSH keys of the host system are not available in the container during the build.

I could probably copy the key in the container and delete it from there at the end of the build process.  However, for this, I would need to hard-code the path to the key in the definition file, which is bad when using the same definition file on another machine where the path is different.
Is there a more portable way of making the `git clone` work during the build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This answer is based on discussions with drdaved on the Apptainer Slack.*

The way we found to do this was to let the Apptainer build process **use the host machine's `ssh-agent`** by setting the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable. That way, if your key is known to the agent on the host, it can be used in the container during build.

The `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` on the host **must be bound into the container**.
Check where your `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is on the host; if it's in a directory that is already bound into the container during build (e.g. `/tmp`), you're ready to go.
Otherwise, you need to bind it in manually.
A common location for the socket is something like `/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`, so you could add `--bind /run` into the container build command.

The advantage of this method is that **the key is at no point copied to the container image**.
The only information that is stored is the socket that your host machine's `ssh-agent` was running on.
AFAIK this is not a security issue.

Note that we have to do some mild trickery as environment variables on the host are not passed to the build process, and there is no way of directly setting environment variables in the build command. Hence, we set via `--build-arg`, and use the build arg in `%post` to set the environment variable.

Example `test.def` file:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: ubuntu:latest

%post
    apt update
    apt install git -y

    export SSH_AUTH_SOCK={{ SSH_AUTH_SOCK }}
    git clone git@github.com:luator/private-repo.git
```

Build command (if your `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` **will** already bound to the container):

```
apptainer build --build-arg SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK test.sif test.def
```

Build command (if your `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` **will not** already bound to the container, and is available at `/run/...`):

```
apptainer build --build-arg SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK --bind /run test.sif test.def
```

Comment: Cool, this is the kind of solution I was hoping for!  It isn't working as is for me, though, as `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` points to `/run/user/...` on my system, which is not bound in the container by default.  So for it to work, I had to add `--bind /run:/run:ro` (not sure if the read-only flag is needed, but feels saver that way :) ).

Comment: Hm, interesting. Have you checked to see whether the stuff you bound in is visible in the built container?

Comment: They are only bound during build-time and not permanently added to the container.  So I think it should be safe.  I'm wondering why it doesn't seem to be necessary for you, though.  Does `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` point to a different location in your case?

Comment: Aha, mine was in `/tmp` (I was using a shared cluster), which is automatically bound at build time (I think). I'll update the answer to incorporate your comment.

Answer (score 4):

You would need a method that does not require hardcoding the path to the key. That involves mounting the SSH key as a temporary file within the container during the build.

Before starting the build, read your SSH key into an environment variable, in a shell on the host system:

```bash
export SSH_KEY=$(cat /path/to/your/ssh/key)
```

In your [Singularity definition file](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/latest/user-guide/definition_files.html), use the [`%setup` section](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/latest/user-guide/definition_files.html#setup) to create a temporary file inside the build environment and write the SSH key to it. Since `%setup` runs on the host system, but can affect the build environment, you can use it to pass the key.

```
%setup
    echo "$SSH_KEY" > $SINGULARITY_ROOTFS/tmp/ssh_key
```

In the [`%post` section](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/latest/user-guide/definition_files.html#post), move the SSH key to a proper location, set the right permissions, and configure SSH to use it.

```
%post
    mkdir -p $HOME/.ssh
    mv /tmp/ssh_key $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
    chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
    echo "Host github.com\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\tIdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa" > $HOME/.ssh/config
    git clone git@github.com:luator/private_repo.git
    rm -f $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Now, build your Singularity image as usual. The SSH key will be used for the `git clone` operation and then removed.

That would make sure your SSH key is only used temporarily during the build and does not get hard-coded into the image. Do unset the `SSH_KEY` environment variable or close the terminal session to prevent the key from remaining in the environment.

Note there is a potential concern: if the image is saved or cached during the build process (especially after the `%post` section where the key is still present), there might be a risk of the key being recoverable from these intermediate layers or snapshots. That risk needs to be assessed based on how Singularity/Apptainer handles intermediate layers during the build process.

Still, this approach makes sure the same `.def` file can be used on different machines. The only requirement is to set the `SSH_KEY` environment variable appropriately on each host before initiating the build.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [docker Buildkit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/), `export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` to enable this feature:

And afterwards just generate your ssh keys (`ssh-keygen` and be sure that your public key - `id_rsa.pub` file content is in your github/gitlab/bitbucket)

Simple usage in a Dockerfile:

```
# use you base image
FROM centos AS build
  
RUM yum install -y git

RUN mkdir -m 700 /root/.ssh; \
    touch -m 600 /root/.ssh/known_hosts; \
    ssh-keyscan github.com &gt; /root/.ssh/known_hosts

# update with tour repo
RUN --mount=type=ssh,id=github git clone git@github.com:<USER>/<REPO>.git
```

And then build the image `RUN --mount=type=ssh,id=github git clone git@github.com:<USER>/<REPO>.git`

Comment: So your suggestion is to use a Dockerfile and build this with Singularity?  While this might work, it is unfortunately not an option in my case as my image is based on another, already existing Singularity image (which I assume is not supported with a Dockerfile).